# PrimeFaces 3.0 - How do I prevent <p:layoutUnit> from displaying border and/or scrollbars?

Tags: jsf, layout, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using PrimeFaces 3.0 and I want to incorporate the `<p:layout>` into my pages. The layout component in 'fullPage' mode does a nice job of dividing up the page, but I have some issues with the look-and-feel of it. Here is what my test page looks like:

[image]

Look specifically at the bottom/south layout unit. There are two things I want to change.

1. How can I stop it from displaying that layout unit with a border around it?
2. How can I stop it from displaying the scrollbar when the content is too big to fit? I just want it to clip the content.

I just purchased the PrimeFaces 2.2 manual (there isn't a 3.0 manual yet), but it doesn't speak to this kind of change.  Do I need to perform some CSS styling magic?

Comment: *Do I need to perform some CSS styling magic?* Yes! :)

Comment: @BalusC You're hilarious. >:|   I'll start messing around with some CSS after lunch. This will be my first attempt at overriding the CSS skinning classes that PrimeFaces uses. Maybe it won't be such a big deal. The manual says that '.ui-layout-unit' is used to style each layout unit container.

Comment: Firefox+Firebug or Chrome+Devtools is extremely helpful in this. Open page in browser, rightclick section of interest, choose *Inspect Element* and you'll see all CSS declarations of it in a console. You can even edit/toggle the separate CSS properties. Once you found the right one, add it in your own CSS or `<style>`. E.g. `.some-layout-class { border: 0; overflow: hidden; }` or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two primary browser types in service in my target environment are IE 6 and IE 7. Unfortunately, I was only able to fix issue #1 for these browsers. The CSS to make the border stop displaying is:

```
.ui-layout-pane-south {
    border: 0;
}
```

If I wanted ALL of the layout unit boxes to stop displaying the border, it would have been:

```
.ui-layout-pane {
    border: 0;
}
```

I followed the suggestion from BalusC to try using Firefox/Firebug to inspect the HTML and play around with the CSS styles. It appears that the key theme-based CSS styles at play here are: `.ui-layout-pane-south`, `.ui-layout-unit-content`, `.ui-layout-south`.

I tried messing with all of them, but I can't get IE 7 (the IE version on my development workstation) to stop showing the overflow scrollbar. Firefox 4 never showed the scrollbar in the first place.

In any case, the border was the most important thing to get rid of and that's now fixed. I can prevent the overflow scrollbar by being careful not to overflow the bounds of my layout unit boxes.

Answer (score 3):

put:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-layout-unit{
             border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: How can I use this for just one element ?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue 2 by this:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="north" styleClass="noScrolllayoutUnit">
        <ui:include src="/templates/header.xhtml" />
</p:layoutUnit>
```

and in css

```
.noScrolllayoutUnit .ui-layout-unit-content{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add border:0; in p:layoutUnit style:
It works perfectly.

```html
<p:layoutUnit position="north" size="50" style="border: 0;">
         <h:panelGrid id="loginPanelGrid"  bgcolor="#E1F5A9"  width="99%" columns="2" style="height:30px;">
           <h:form id="homeHeaderForm">
             <h:outputText value="Hello #{loginBean.userDetails.employee.name}" style="color:red;font-size: 15px;margin-left: 75%"/>
             <p:commandButton style="background: #3498db;width:80px;height:25px;font-family: Arial;color: #ffffff;font-size: 13px;margin-left: 5%;" 
                              action="#{loginBean.logOut}" value="Log Out" ajax="false">
                </p:commandButton>
              </h:form>  
         </h:panelGrid>
 </p:layoutUnit>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the scroll bar in ALL panes of the layout, you have to override the css property "overflow" with "hidden" in the ui-layout-unit class. The default is "auto".
To get rid of the the scroll bar in one or more specific panes of the layout, setting the property in the ui-layout-{position} class will not work as one might expect. Setting the property on the contained element will work.
So in your case you would have to set `style="overflow: hidden"` on the `<h:outputText>` element or whatever produces the text "south content ...".

Answer (score -1):

@Mohammed If you want to apply it on one element you can do the follow:

```
<p:layoutUnit styleClass="ui-layout-unit">
     ...
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Also you need to have the custom css defined somewhere like in user1852036's answer:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-layout-unit{
        border: none;
    }
</style>
```